# How to pass HTTP header details in response to POST request

Tags: python, python-requests

Please note that I am still very green to the world of coding and have only been writing code for a week. Thus please forgive me if my question is stupid.

My current objective is to log into a website with my python script.

I need to take information out of the HTTP response headers and add it to my POST, this is my current script:

```
import requests

targetURL = "http://website.com/login.aspx"

headers = { "Host": "192.168.56.101",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"}

get_request = requests.get(url=targetURL,
                           headers=headers)
```

The response I get is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache,no-cache
Content-Length: 15748
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=123456
```

How does one create a HTTP post with the information received from the above?

Any information would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `requests.get` is an object with properties that you can access.  Try the following:

```
response = requests.get(url=targetURL, headers=headers)
response_headers = response.headers
```

`response_headers` is a dictionary.  You can modify it and pass it to whatever you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response.